# Forwarding over a vpn

Tags: linux, vpn, ufw

I have a group of AWS web servers which will need to get into the business of initiating and speaking TCP over a VPN to a third party. Don't ask me why a VPN is the third party's chosen solution; that's out of my control. The individual servers within the group don't persist; they come up and down with releases. Meanwhile, the third party requires static IPs, among other things.

The general thought is to set up a gateway server (or realistically, a couple of gateway servers so it can handle our release cycle) as the VPN clients and terminate the VPN there. Our web servers would only know about the VPN gateway servers; the third party servers would only know about the gateway servers; the gateway servers relay everything accordingly, sending it over the VPN or plain TCP as appropriate.

The question is, of course, how best to handle the relay. The gateway server will be Ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04. I'm hoping that I can handle this with UFW and OpenVPN -- UFW handling IP redirection and passing off to the appropriate interfaces, while OpenVPN essentially wraps a network interface. Is this a realistic scheme?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPN_CloudHub.html

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to use an [Amazon VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Introduction.html) and launch your instances within it, using private addresses - the full setup procedure is outside the scope of a ServerFault answer, but your VPC will be a locked-off area of Amazon.

You can optionally set up your instances with public IP addresses if you need the servers to be publicly accessible, but your question doesn't mention public accessibility.

Once you have a VPC in place, you can use [Amazon's VPN connectivity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html) to directly connect the third party's router to the Amazon VPC, and statically route all traffic for your VPC's subnet(s) across the tunnel.